# Specifying LUIS dialog spellCheck, slot programmatically

Tags: botframework

so far I was able to avoid hardcoding my LUIS appId and key by doing the following:

```
var luisService = new LuisService(new LuisModelAttribute(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LuisAppId"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LuisAppKey"]));
context.Call(new LuisDialog(luisService), ResumeAfterDialog);
```

And then having my LUIS dialog declared as:

```
[Serializable]
public class LuisDialog : LuisDialog<object>
{
    public LuisDialog(ILuisService ls) : base(ls)
    {
    }
    ....
}
```

}

But I would also like to be able to set SpellCheck=true, Log, Verbose and other parameters available in the LuisModel attribute programmatically, is there a way of doing that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I just need to set the LuisModelAttribute properties in code before creating the LuisService:

```
var luisSettings = new LuisModelAttribute(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LuisAppId"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LuisAppKey"]);
luisSettings.Log = true;
luisSettings.SpellCheck = true;
luisSettings.Log = true;
var luisService = new LuisService(luisSettings);
context.Call(new LuisDialog(luisService), ResumeAfterDialog);
```